# How to to subscribe and generate K-line

Tags: python, c++, dolphindb

I want to subscribe and generate K-line,the ticks is the stream table (receive tick data in real time). The names and types of the columns are as follows:

```py
tbColNames=
`TradingDay`InstrumentID`ExchangeID`ExchangeInstID`LastPrice`Volume`Amount`OpenPosition`PreSettlementPrice`PreClosePrice`PreOpenInterest`OpenPrice`HighestPrice`LowestPrice`TotalVolume`TotalTurnover`OpenInterest`ClosePrice`SettlementPrice`UpperLimitPrice`LowerLimitPrice`ActionTime`RecvTime`BidPrice1`BidVolume1`AskPrice1`AskVolume1`BidPrice2`BidVolume2`AskPrice2`AskVolume2`BidPrice3`BidVolume3`AskPrice3`AskVolume3`BidPrice4`BidVolume4`AskPrice4`AskVolume4`BidPrice5`BidVolume5`AskPrice5`AskVolume5`AveragePrice`PreDelta`CurrDelta`RecordNo`TotalRecordNo`InDbTime
tbColTypes=[DATE,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,INT,TIMESTAMP]
///////// create an empty table
tbTicks = streamTable(100000:0,tbColNames,tbColTypes)
//////////  share this table
share  tbTicks as ticks
//////////  set the stream table(tbTicks) to prsistence
enableTableShareAndPersistence(table=tbTicks, tableName=`ticks, cacheSize=2000000, retentionMinutes=4320 )
```

The above part has been successful
Now I want to subscribe to the stream table and generate a 1-minute K line. On the GUI console, perform the following operations

```py
barColNames=`ActionTime`InstrumentID`Open`High`Low`Close`Volume`Amount`OpenPosition`TradingDay
barColTypes=[DATETIME,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DATE]

share streamTable(100:0, barColNames, barColTypes) as traders

share keyedTable(`ActionTime`InstrumentID,100:0, barColNames, barColTypes) as barsMin01
metrics=<[
first(LastPrice) ,
max(LastPrice) ,
min(LastPrice) ,
last(LastPrice),
sum(Volume),
sum(Amount) ,
sum(OpenPosition) ,
last(TradingDay) ]>

tsAggrKline = createTimeSeriesAggregator(name="aggr_kline_min01", windowSize=600000, step=600000, metrics=metrics, dummyTable=traders, outputTable=barsMin01, timeColumn=`ActionTime, keyColumn=`InstrumentID,updateTime=500, useWindowStartTime=true)

subscribeTable(tableName="ticks", actionName="act_tsaggr", offset=1, handler=append!{tsAggrKline}, msgAsTable=true)
```

But when the aggregation engine (tsAggrKline) is executed, the following error is prompted:

```py
Unrecognized column name LastPrice
```

I don't know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code:

```py
tbColNames=
`TradingDay`InstrumentID`ExchangeID`ExchangeInstID`LastPrice`Volume`Amount`OpenPosition`PreSettlementPrice`PreClosePrice`PreOpenInterest`OpenPrice`HighestPrice`LowestPrice`TotalVolume`TotalTurnover`OpenInterest`ClosePrice`SettlementPrice`UpperLimitPrice`LowerLimitPrice`ActionTime`RecvTime`BidPrice1`BidVolume1`AskPrice1`AskVolume1`BidPrice2`BidVolume2`AskPrice2`AskVolume2`BidPrice3`BidVolume3`AskPrice3`AskVolume3`BidPrice4`BidVolume4`AskPrice4`AskVolume4`BidPrice5`BidVolume5`AskPrice5`AskVolume5`AveragePrice`PreDelta`CurrDelta`RecordNo`TotalRecordNo`InDbTime

tbColTypes=[DATE,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,INT,TIMESTAMP]
///////// create an empty table
tbTicks = streamTable(100000:0,tbColNames,tbColTypes)

enableTableShareAndPersistence(table=tbTicks, tableName=`ticks, cacheSize=2000000, retentionMinutes=4320 )

barColNames=`UpdateTime`InstrumentID`Open`High`Low`Close`Volume`Amount`OpenPosition`TradingDay
barColTypes=[TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DATE]
share streamTable(100:0, barColNames, barColTypes) as traders
metrics=<[
first(LastPrice),
max(LastPrice),
min(LastPrice),
last(LastPrice),
sum(Volume),
sum(Amount),
sum(OpenPosition),
last(TradingDay)]>

tsAggrKline = createTimeSeriesAggregator(name="aggr_kline_min01", windowSize=600000, step=600000, metrics=metrics, dummyTable=ticks, outputTable=traders, timeColumn=`InDbTime, keyColumn=`InstrumentID,updateTime=500, useWindowStartTime=true)

subscribeTable(tableName="ticks", actionName="act_tsaggr", offset=-1, handler=append!{getStreamEngine("aggr_kline_min01")}, batchSize=1000, throttle=1, hash=0, msgAsTable=true)
```